# Is it possible to schedule a change a Heroku ENV variable's value via a script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an ENV variable in Heroku that I would like to toggle between false and true during a specific day in the month for a Ruby on Rails application.  Is there a way to automate this via a script or something?  I don't want to have to get up at midnight to do it.

Comment: write the script and setup cron schedule for this. It will automatically run the script.

Comment: Ah I see, I could probably fire off a rake task to do it

Comment: Yes you are. You can use rake task.